# Selenium Python - Custom Explicit Wait(s) Helper method / function

Tags: python, selenium, automation, wait, helper

First of all thanks for any feedback!

So:

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Python (mostly for automated testing)

I have a Python Automation file named: automation.py - for example.

1 - I want to open Google.com (for explaining purpose)

2 - I want to wait until the Search field is displayed using a custom function

At the moment I can do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
```

I want to create another Python file, from which I can import a custom method / function to refactor the "wait" code.

Something like:

```
waitfor(e, locator, 10)
```

where:

e = element

locator = locator (XPATH, NAME, ID etc.)

10 = wait time

Thanks and sorry for bothering!

Answer (score 1):

You can customize it like the following.

```
def waitfor(locator, timeout):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator)
```

You can call it from another file like

```
locator = (By.NAME, "q")
waitfor(locator,10)
```